# In keyEvent, How can I catch the key " * "?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, key

```
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == 8){
        $scope.erase();
    }

    else if(keyEvent.keyCode === 107){
    console.log("+");
    $scope.inputToCal('+')
    }

    else if(keyEvent.keyCode === 109){
    console.log("-");
    $scope.inputToCal('-')
    }

    else if(keyEvent.keyCode === 16){
    console.log("*");
    $scope.inputToCal('*')
}
    }

    else if(keyEvent.keyCode === 111){
    console.log("/");
    $scope.inputToCal('/')
    }
```

I was trying to make a calculator that catch the "keydown".

I can catch these keys, "+","-","/".

These keys code are "107","109","111"

However, there is one problem.

I can't catch the key "*".

Are there any solution to solve this problem?

Or, do I have to define new array to catch the key "Shift"(keyCode:16) , and "8"(keyCode:56) ?

Sorry , I'm a newbie about keyEvent.
I'm waiting a solution ...
Please help me!!

Comment: If you use `keypress` instead you'll catch characters that require shift to be pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle shift key press separately.

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
 var shiftPressed=0;
 var event = (e==null ? event:e);
 shiftPressed=event.shiftKey;
 if ((shiftPressed)&& (event.keyCode==56)) 
   alert ("You pressed * key");
 return true;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/soxj0v54/1/

For your code it will look like-

```
else if(keyEvent.keyCode === 56 && keyEvent.shiftKey){
    console.log("*");
    $scope.inputToCal('*')
}
```